# Validate for unique composite key in an excel using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating an excel macro. As part of that I need to validate unique composite key in an Excel . ie say Column1 + Column2 + Column3 shouldn't be repeating.

If so the row should be highlighted in red color.

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: if you post the code you've tried, we can help a lot easier. That said, you don't even need VBA, from the sound of it. You can use conditional formatting to accomplish this (not sure if it's possible in 2003, but if you have 2007 +, you can do it).

Comment: I suggest you to use conditional formatting

Comment: if you're doing VBA for this, iterate over the rows, for each row concatenate the values from col 1-3, and store them in a 1 dimensional array. Use a `MATCH` function to check if the value already exists, if so, color the row red. If you get hung up on this, post your code and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks all .. I will have to use Macro for this operation as this is just one of the validations that need to be done before lot of other things are done by the same macro.

Comment: @DavidZemens .. Thanks for the help..Iam on it..Ill reply if I need any help

Comment: If doing in vba i would use either `collection` or a `dictionary`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this: Two depend on sorting your data while the third does not. I'll supply them in different answers so readers can indicate which they prefer.

#### Identify duplicates using a Dictionary in VBA

**Pro:** Fast, does not require sorting
**Con:** Requires code, does not automatically update

In this case I treat the problem of actually identifying the duplicate rows separately from the trivial step of highlighting them. This function returns a Dictionary where the keys are the compound keys that have more than one row and the values are Collections containing the row numbers of all the rows which matched the key. It's the equivalent of a `Dictionary<string,List<int>>` in .NET. Conceptually it looks like this:

```
"some..key..1" : [1, 42, 401]
"some..key..2" : [134, 135]
```

The keys are the concatenated contents of each of the key columns, delimited by a null character. I use the unprintable null character so that the key set ("A", "Dog", "2") does not become equal to ("AD", "o", "g2").

As written the key comparison is case-sensitive. If you desire a case-insensitive match, set the `CompareMode` property of `dctValues` and `dctDuplicates` to `TextCompare`.

**Note**: You'll need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

```
Public Function FindDuplicates(ByVal DataRange As Range, ParamArray KeyColumns()) As Dictionary
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vKeyRange, rngCol As Range
    Dim dctKeys As New Dictionary
    Dim colKeys
    Dim keyParts() As String
    Dim strKey As String
    Dim dctValues As New Dictionary
    Dim dctDuplicates As New Dictionary
    Dim i As Long, ub As Long
    Dim lngFirstRow As Long, lngLastRow As Long, lngRow As Long

    Set ws = DataRange.Worksheet

    ' Identify unique key column numbers
    For Each vKeyRange In KeyColumns
        For Each rngCol In vKeyRange.Columns
            dctKeys(rngCol.Column) = True
        Next
    Next
    colKeys = dctKeys.Keys

    ub = UBound(colKeys)
    ReDim keyParts(ub)

    ' Find first and last row of data range
    lngFirstRow = DataRange.Cells(1, 1).Row
    lngLastRow = DataRange.Cells(DataRange.Rows.Count, 1).Row

    ' Loop through rows
    For lngRow = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow
        ' Get the parts for the key
        For i = 0 To ub
            keyParts(i) = ws.Cells(lngRow, colKeys(i)).Value
        Next

        ' Concatenate the parts with an unprintable character as
        ' the delimiter, so that "A" + "Dog" != "AD" + "og"
        strKey = Join(keyParts, Chr(0))

        ' If the key hasn't been found yet, create a new collection
        If Not dctValues.Exists(strKey) Then
            dctValues.Add strKey, New Collection
        End If

        ' Push the row number to the list of rows with this key
        dctValues(strKey).Add lngRow

        ' If this is the second row with this key, add the
        ' list to the dictionary of keys with multiple rows
        If dctValues(strKey).Count = 2 Then
            dctDuplicates.Add strKey, dctValues(strKey)
        End If
    Next

    Set FindDuplicates = dctDuplicates
End Function
```

Usage: Find all duplicate rows in A2:I5000, using columns A, B, and E as key columns

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, dctDups As Dictionary, vKey, vRow
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set dctDups = FindDuplicates(ws.Range("A2:I5000"), ws.Range("A:B"), ws.Range("E:E"))
For Each vKey In dctDups
    For Each vRow In dctDups(vKey)
        ws.Range("A" & vRow & ":I" & vRow).Interior.Color = vbRed
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Just wanted to add on..ws.Range("E:E")worked instaed of ws.Range("E")

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to accomplish this: Two depend on sorting your data while the third does not. I'll supply them in different answers so readers can indicate which they prefer.

#### Sort and apply conditional formatting

**Pro:** Dynamic (adjusts to changes in data), does not require any code
**Con:** Requires sorting, can become messy

1. Manually sort by the key columns
2. Create a conditional formatting rule and apply it to all rows of data.

   1. Highlight all the data, but starting with the first row of data
   2. Select Conditional Formatting -> New Rule
   3. Set the format to a red fill
   4. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
   5. Here's the formula you need, assuming your **selection starts on row 2** (there's a header in row 1), and your **key columns are A, B, and C**. Note carefully where the `$` signs appear and where they do not:

      ```
      =OR((CONCATENATE($A2,$B2,$C2)=CONCATENATE($A1,$B1,$C1)),
          (CONCATENATE($A2,$B2,$C2)=CONCATENATE($A3,$B3,$C3)))
      ```

      This will highlight *both* rows that have duplicate keys, or all rows if there are more than two.

Comment: Sorting is not required if you are using the countif formula

Comment: @Pynner How would you use COUNTIF to compare concatenated values of multiple cells? If you do have a way you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Wait, can you go through roughly as to how this works? What sorting do you need to do beforehand? Also, what is the third way?

Comment: Is there a way to make this solution ignore blanks? Also, is there a way to do this using the Data Validation feature instead of conditional formatting to generate an error message when the key set entered is not unique?